How to get Ubuntu Frame Launcher working?
I'm trying to use Ubuntu Frame Launcher but it doesn't seem to be working.
Following the directions here: https://mir-server.io/docs/ubuntu-frame-configuration-options
When running sudo snap connect ubuntu-frame:desktop-launch I get error: snap "ubuntu-frame" has no plug named "desktop-launch"
I think this is my problem because the other 2 commands complete successfully.  I do not see a side bar or anything that seems to allow me to select other apps.  I have wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk running successfully and showing the webpage I'd like.
Edit: I guess this is caused by ubuntu-frame not supporting that slot/plug, although directions say it should be
